# Loop for setting a tkinter widget name

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

How do I create a loop for naming label widget. I do not know how to set the widget name as a variable.

```
from tkinter import *

def dofunc():
    v1.set("one")
    v2.set("two")
    v3.set("three")
    widget4.config(text="four")

v1=StringVar()
widget1=Label(root,width=10,textvariable=v1)
widget1.pack()

v2=StringVar()
widget2=Label(root,width=10,textvariable=v2)
widget2.pack()

v3=StringVar()
widget3=Label(root,width=10,textvariable=v3)
widget3.pack()

widget4=Label(root,width=10)
widget4.pack()

root.geometry("+50+50")
root.after(500, dofunc)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What is your definition of a widget's name? It's text option?

Comment: yes... define as text ... widget1, widget2,,,,,widget4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the answer you are looking for is a container?

```
bag_o_widgets = {}  # A dict because you said "name", it could equally be an list with numbers for names.
def dofunc():
    for i in range(1,4):  # Generates 1,2 and 3 as inputs to the str() function for "naming".
        v = StringVar()
        bag_o_widgets[str(i)] = Label(root, width=10, textvariable=v)
        bag_o_widgets[str(i)].pack()
    bag_o_widgets["4"] = Label(root,width=10)
    bag_o_widgets["4"].pack()
    bag_o_widgets["4"].config(text="four")
    return bag_o_widgets
```

This is the canonical way of naming variables in a loop.

A nasty literal hack would be to use polymorphic code instead.

Comment: john.. modifying your code... i have traceback "KeyError: 1"  from tkinter import *

def dofunc():
    bag_o_widgets[1].config(text='ok')

root=Tk()  
  
bag_o_widgets = {} 
for i in range(1,4):
    v = StringVar()
    bag_o_widgets[str(i)] = Label(root, width=10,text=str(i), textvariable=v)
    bag_o_widgets[str(i)].pack()

print(bag_o_widgets)
root.after(100,dofunc)
root.mainloop

Answer (score 0):

from John's code.. I use it this way...

```
from tkinter import *

def dofunc():
    bag_o_widgets[str(2)].config(text='two')
    bag_o_widgets[str(5)].config(text='five')
    bag_o_widgets[str(10)].config(text='ten')
    bag_o_widgets[str(17)].config(text='seventeen')

root=Tk()  

bag_o_widgets = {} 
for i in range(1,21):
    bag_o_widgets[str(i)] = Label(root, width=15)
    bag_o_widgets[str(i)].pack()

root.after(100,dofunc)
root.mainloop()
```